# Vectorized way to combine two dataframes into a y=mx+b result

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two pandas dataframes.  One is a timeseries of `m` and `b` values from the typical `y=mx+b` function.  The other dataframe (could be considered a series) is the `x` value for several different categories.   (yes, the `x` is held fixed, and the linear parameters change in this situation)

What I want to do is generate a new dataframe where the index is the `formula_df.index`,  the columns are the `staff.columns`,  and the value = `mx+b` that comes from multiplying the values of staff_df to the `formula_df[m]` and adding `formula[b]`.

As a concrete example, `final_df.loc[pd.IndexSlice['20191204', 'matt']]` would be: (22 * 0.90 + 10)

```
staff = {"mike": 18,  "matt": 22,  "dave": 25, "kanad": 15, 'elder':85}
staff_df = pd.DataFrame(data=staff, index = ['measurement'])
staff_df.index.name="evaluation"


the_data = {'m': [.5, .1, .3, .9, 1.2], 'b':[12, 14, 8, 10, 20]}
formula_df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(start="20191201", periods=5, freq="d"),
                         data=the_data)
formula_df.index.name="Date"
```

Even just trying to make the `mx` part of the equation fails.  I have tried to do things like `formula_df['m']*staff_df` but it gives nonsense result.   I suppose if I knew `numpy` better, it would be clear what to do, alas I don't.  I suspect this involves something about `broadcasting` but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `final_df` `DataFrame` by constructor by columns and index names and data are converted first column to numpy array, then multiple by [`DataFrame.mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html) and add column by [`DataFrame.add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add.html):

```
final_df = pd.DataFrame(data=[staff_df.iloc[0].to_numpy()], 
                        index=formula_df.index, 
                        columns=staff_df.columns)
final_df = final_df.mul(formula_df['m'], axis=0).add(formula_df['b'], axis=0)

print (final_df)
            mike  matt  dave  kanad  elder
Date                                      
2019-12-01  21.0  23.0  24.5   19.5   54.5
2019-12-02  15.8  16.2  16.5   15.5   22.5
2019-12-03  13.4  14.6  15.5   12.5   33.5
2019-12-04  26.2  29.8  32.5   23.5   86.5 <- 22 * 0.90 + 10 = 29.8
2019-12-05  41.6  46.4  50.0   38.0  122.0
```