# Populating dataframe with multindex columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have this [neat solution to my simpler problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59450671/3556757) of doing some vectorized arithmetic between two dataframes.  The basic trick was to pre-populate the final dataframe with the values from one dataframe first.

My new situation is that the dataframe has a multindex column, not a simple 1-level column. So I'm not clear how to coerce pandas to do the same operation from my first question in a dataframe with multindex.

The original + more complex example:

```
#the original solution
staff = {"mike": 18,  "matt": 22,  "dave": 25, "kanad": 15, 'elder':85}
staff_df = pd.DataFrame(data=staff, index = ['measurement'])
staff_df.index.name="evaluation"


the_data = {'m': [.5, .1, .3, .9, 1.2], 'b':[12, 14, 8, 10, 20]}
formula_df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(start="20191201", periods=5, freq="d"),
                         data=the_data)
formula_df.index.name="Date"
final_df = pd.DataFrame(data=[staff_df.iloc[0].to_numpy()], 
                        index=formula_df.index, 
                        columns=staff_df.columns)
final_df = final_df.mul(formula_df['m'], axis=0).add(formula_df['b'], axis=0)



#with a mult-index column
arrays = [['mike', 'mike', 'matt', 'matt', 'dave','dave',  'elder','elder', ], ['day', 'night']*4, ]
cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays, names=('name', 'period'), )
staff_df = pd.DataFrame(data= [[10,11, 13,8, 19,22, 7, 12]]  , columns=cols, index=["measurement"])
staff_df.index.names=["evaluation", ]

the_data = {'m': [.5, .1, .3, .9, 1.2], 'b':[12, 14, 8, 10, 20]}
formula_df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(start="20191201", periods=5, freq="d"),
                         data=the_data)
formula_df.index.name="Date"


""" how to generate the final_df for this multi-index column example?"""
```

UPDATE:

Sorry, this second 'toy' example doesn't replicate my real problem.  With the new multiindex, there are 4(mike, matt, dave, kanad) x 2(day, night) =8 columns of data.   So in my toy, I passed a list of 8 digits as the data, so there is no problem.

But in my real life example, the values for the "mike matt dave kand" level are identical for both day and night level.  So I only have 4 data points to pass in, not eight.  I need to somehow duplicate those data correctly.

IE: in my real example:

```
fuel_gpw = pd.DataFrame(index=sulfur['asia'].index,
                       columns=yield_df.unstack(level=0).columns, 
                       data=[resid_df.iloc[0].to_numpy()])
```

the columns is length 135  (5x27)  but the data is only length 27,  so I get a `ValueError: 135 columns passed, passed data had 27 columns`.

I need to duplicate the `[resid_df.iloc[0].to_numpy()]`  from `[a,b,c,..z]` to `[a,a,a,a,a,b,b,b,b,b,....z,z,z,z,z]` I suppose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if understand, but for me working same solution:

```
final_df = pd.DataFrame(data=[staff_df.iloc[0].to_numpy()], 
                        index=formula_df.index, 
                        columns=staff_df.columns)
final_df = final_df.mul(formula_df['m'], axis=0).add(formula_df['b'], axis=0)
print (final_df)
name        mike        matt        dave       elder      
period       day night   day night   day night   day night
2019-12-01  17.0  17.5  18.5  16.0  21.5  23.0  15.5  18.0
2019-12-02  15.0  15.1  15.3  14.8  15.9  16.2  14.7  15.2
2019-12-03  11.0  11.3  11.9  10.4  13.7  14.6  10.1  11.6
2019-12-04  19.0  19.9  21.7  17.2  27.1  29.8  16.3  20.8
2019-12-05  32.0  33.2  35.6  29.6  42.8  46.4  28.4  34.4
```

EDIT:

There should be used [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
final_df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4]],
                       index=formula_df.index, 
                        columns=staff_df.columns.levels[0])

print (final_df)
name        dave  elder  matt  mike
Date                               
2019-12-01     1      2     3     4
2019-12-02     1      2     3     4
2019-12-03     1      2     3     4
2019-12-04     1      2     3     4
2019-12-05     1      2     3     4

final_df = final_df.reindex(staff_df.columns, level=0, axis=1)
print (final_df)
name       mike       matt       dave       elder      
period      day night  day night  day night   day night
Date                                                   
2019-12-01    4     4    3     3    1     1     2     2
2019-12-02    4     4    3     3    1     1     2     2
2019-12-03    4     4    3     3    1     1     2     2
2019-12-04    4     4    3     3    1     1     2     2
2019-12-05    4     4    3     3    1     1     2     2
```

Comment: yeah, sorry my toy example didn't replicate the problem.  I have edited the question with a clearer explanation of the problem.

Comment: @user3556757 - Can you check edit? Because if understand well, you need `reindex` by second level for repeating

Comment: Yes, you understood me properly.  `reindex` was the key.  Somehow I have been totally unaware of this function. I need to study it now -- seems very vital. I think I have a lot of old code that could be cleaned up by using it instead.  Thanks always for your very clear code-style.